# Magento2 Recently viewed widget not working

Tags: magento2, widgets

I am working on a new Magento2 website and need to implement the recently viewed section on a page.

I tried using Magento's default widget and double checked all configurations but its output is not showing on the page.

I have created a container in My theme on Home page and assigning a widget in the same container. I can assign static blocks and output shows fine but not recently viewed widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling your FPC. Magento2 has some issue with this as far as recently viewed widgets concern.

Comment: got it, any solution?

Comment: Disabled. Still no data.